# Shell script that reads a file and executes a command

Tags: linux, shell, script

I want to write a script which reads a file and executes a command for each row in the file. This command contains a variable for which we need to pass each row in the file.

File has only one column and close to 500 rows.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f $1 ]; then
        while read line; do
                ./execute.sh $line;
        done < "$1"
fi
```

To execute, ./script.sh datafile.txt

Comment: I am assuming $1 is the filename right? or a variable declared like $1=/home/file.txt ??

Comment: Yes, $1 is the first argument passed to the shell script from the command line, so *datafile.txt* in the example `./script.sh` ***`datafile.txt`***.

Comment: Correct. Just define your script as execute.sh, and put those file with aforementioned rows at datafile.txt. You should be able to modify that script to suit your need. $1 is variable for first parameter, in this case, your datafile that contained those parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The `xargs` command with the `-I` option does exactly that:

```
xargs -I {} yourcommand ... {} ... < yourinputfile
```

where `...` are the remaining arguments of your command (if any).
The `{}` part is replaced by every line from `yourinputfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear but if you want to write a script to execute another file, Try below command:

`if [ -f /home/sepahrad/MyFile ]; then`

`./MyFile`

`fi`

When you execute your file it executes **MyFile** commands one by one. You have to replace your file address instead of **/home/sepahrad/MyFile**.

Comment: I want to send each row in this file as a variable into the command...example: command $/home/sepahrad/MyFile -c username -p password

Comment: Now how do i pass each row into the command...else shall i use for loop in this case?

Comment: Oh i got it, Try `awk` command, $0 in awk command means all of line, and you know that `awk` command check each line of file, Or use While to read each line.

Comment: Salour... i tried using this awk for a different purpose and it worked

Comment: Good news ... :)